# read all image files from folder for processing

Tags: java, android, image-processing

I am working on an android application which works on processing images using specified algorithms MSE and SSI for comparing the structure of images.

I have working code which allows me to select two images from a chosen folder and perform the required operations on them, however the next step is to allow the user to choose a folder which will then automatically read all the images and perform the operations required and save the images which are found to be similar.

I have the following code but at the minute it is working through the images and it will eventually through a time out error.

Is there anything I am doing wrong, or that I should change in order for this to run smoothly. There is 172 images in the folder which needs to be processed.

```
public void addItemsOnSpinner() {
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("New images");
    list.add("All downloads");
    list.add("Bluetooth");
    list.add("Camera shots");
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    selection = String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem());
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int n =0;
    if (v == submit) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 172; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 172; j++) {
                absoluteFilePath = folder +  "/" + selection + "/image" + i + ".bmp";
                bMap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(absoluteFilePath);
                absoluteFilePath2 = folder +  "/" + selection + "/image" + j + ".bmp";
                bMap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(absoluteFilePath2);
                Toast.makeText(LoadFile.this, "Comparing Image" + i + " against Image" + j,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //loop through each image compare image by image
                calculateMSE(bMap1, bMap2, 256, 256);
                calculateSSI(bMap1, bMap2, 4);
                //calculateSSI(bMap1, bMap2, 8);
                //calculateSSI(bMap1, bMap2, 16);
                //calculateSSI(bMap1, bMap2, 32);
                //if images are similar save file paths to array
                if(calculateMSE(bMap1, bMap2, 256, 256) <= 0.4 && calculateSSI(bMap1, bMap2, 4) >= 0.6){
                    ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
                    image1.setImageBitmap(bMap1);
                    ImageView image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView2);
                    image2.setImageBitmap(bMap2);

                    //saving file path to array
                    bitmapArray1 [n] = bMap1;
                    bitmapArray2 [n] = bMap2;
                    n++;
                }
```

Comment: Try with fewer images. If it works, it is very possible that your are running out of memory

Comment: Please provide LogCat output of the error.

Comment: 'code which allows me to select two images from a chosen folder'. If you need images two by two then how would you choose them from a directory listing? 'at the minute it is working through the images ' ??? Please explain what you mean exactly. 'and it will eventually through a time out error.'.  Please explain better what happens.

Comment: You are comparing each file with itself too. Is that ok?

Comment: 'for (int i = 1; i <= 172; i++) ' ??? 172 ???? I don't believe my eyes.

Comment: You are doing all calculates twice and not lookimg at the result of the first ones. Are there side effects?

Comment: ' //if images are similar save file paths to array'. If only you were doing that! Instead you save bitmaps to an array. Yes indeed... you will shortly be out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

You may be doing to much work on the UI thread for the computation.  Run an AsyncTask to run a background thread. Update the UI on progress update and upon finish.

Typical use:

```
// in your onclick method. in function if( v == submit )
new AsyncTask( n, bitmapArray1, bitmapArray2 ).execute( );

// in AsyncTask class
public AsyncTask extends AsyncTask< Boolean, Boolean, Void )
{

 int n;
 Bitmap[] bitmapArray1, bitmapArray2;

 public AsyncTask ( int n, Bitmap[] bitmapArray1, Bitmap[] bitmapArray2 )
 {
  this.n = n;
  this.bitmapArray1 = bitmapArray1;
  this.bitmapArray2 = bitmapArray2;
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPreExecute( )
 {}

 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute( Boolean bool )
 {
  if ( bool )
  {
   ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
                image1.setImageBitmap(bMap1);
                ImageView image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView2);
                image2.setImageBitmap(bMap2);

                //saving file path to array
                bitmapArray1 [n] = bMap1;
                bitmapArray2 [n] = bMap2;
  }
 }

 @Override
 protected void onProgressUpdate( Bitmap result )
 {
  // update UI here.
  // best UI update is the progressbar.
  Toast.makeText(LoadFile.this, "Comparing Image" + i + " against Image" + j,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }

 @Override
 protected Boolean doInBackground( Void... params )
 {
  for (int i = 1; i <= 172; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 172; j++) {
            absoluteFilePath = folder +  "/" + selection + "/image" + i + ".bmp";
            bMap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(absoluteFilePath);
            absoluteFilePath2 = folder +  "/" + selection + "/image" + j + ".bmp";
            bMap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(absoluteFilePath2);

            //loop through each image compare image by image
            calculateMSE(bMap1, bMap2, 256, 256);
            calculateSSI(bMap1, bMap2, 4);
            //calculateSSI(bMap1, bMap2, 8);
            //calculateSSI(bMap1, bMap2, 16);
            //calculateSSI(bMap1, bMap2, 32);
            //if images are similar save file paths to array
            if(calculateMSE(bMap1, bMap2, 256, 256) <= 0.4 && calculateSSI(bMap1, bMap2, 4) >= 0.6){
                n++;
              return true;
            } else
              return false;
            }
         }
    }
       return null;
 }
}
```